# Autofill textboxes from access database based on one text box value

Tags: vb.net

[I have 3 text boxes and based on Customer Name suggestion other 2 boxes should be auto filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk4Im.png)

I am new to database so I am finding codes on internet and trying to implement it but it
is not working. So please help me with this.
I am working in for Windows Form Application in visual basic.

```
Private Sub AutoComplete()

    'sql = "Select * FROM Table1 where CustomerName='" & custnm.Text & "'"

    com = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    reader = com.ExecuteReader()
    Dim autoComp As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()

    While reader.Read()
        autoComp.Add(reader("CustomerName"))
        autoComp.Add(reader("ContactNO"))
    End While

    reader.Close()
    custnm.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    custnm.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    custnm.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoComp
    contactno.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    contactno.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    contactno.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoComp
    wcontno.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    wcontno.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    wcontno.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoComp

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say AutoFilled, what do you mean?  Are you talking about the browser Auto-Filling?

Comment: If so, you cannot force a browser to Auto-Fill data.  You can tell the browser what type of data value should go in there if the User decides (or even has enabled) to AutoFill.

Comment: But, if by AutoFill you mean pre-populating the TextBoxes with text then you can most definitely do that via server-side or client-side code.   But you cannot force a browser to do it after the request has been completed.

Comment: @JohnPete22  This looks like a WinForms app.

Comment: You have to fill 2 (or more) different `List(Of String)` or `String()` arrays (no need to use a `AutoCompleteStringCollection`, your List/Array is converted to an `AutoCompleteStringCollection` when you set the `AutoCompleteCustomSource`)

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial solution to straighten out your database code. It is too much code to put in a comment.

Keep your database objects local so you can control when they are closed and disposed. Objects that expose a .Dispose method may have unmanaged resources that need to be released. A Using...End Using block will handle this for you even if there is and error.

Always use Parameters to avoid sql injection which can damage your database. Also it makes the sql string easier to write. You will need to check your database for the proper datatype because I had to guess.

A `DataReader` uses an open connection until it is done. You don't want to hold your connection open while you use the data so I chose a `DataTable`. Just load it and pass it off to where you want to use it. The connection and command are closed and disposed.

I wasn't sure why you combined the data in a single `AutoCompleteStringCollection`. It seems that one for each combo box would be better. They are form level variables so you can used them in another method to attach to a combo box.

I think you need to look into `BindingSource` and `BindingNavigator` to sync the combo boxes.

```
Private Function GetData() As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
            com As New OleDbCommand("Select * FROM Table1 where CustomerName= @Name;", con)
        com.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = custnm.Text
        con.Open()
        dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Private autoCompName As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()
Private autoCompNO As New AutoCompleteStringCollection()

Private Sub FillAutoCompleteCollection()
    Dim dt = GetData()
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        autoCompName.Add(row("CustomerName").ToString)
        autoCompNO.Add(row("ContractNO").ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```